# Unable to deploy golang API to AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, go-modules

I'm trying to deploy my Golang API to Elasticbeanstalk, without success.

First, I used platform Go, also tred with Docker but it won't work

Go

It just says this in /var/log/eb-engine.log:

```
2023/11/06 05:36:02.518660 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [FlipApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: Register application failed because the registration of proc web failed:
startProcess Failure: starting process "web" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start web.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for web.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status web.service" and "journalctl -xeu web.service" for details.

2023/11/06 05:36:02.518821 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2023/11/06 05:36:02.519071 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'.","timestamp":1699248958659,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment found and used the 'go.mod' file in your source bundle.","timestamp":1699248960366,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1699248962518,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

When running systemctl status web.service, here is the result, nothing meaningful

```
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: web.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start web.service - This is web daemon.
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: web.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Stopped web.service - This is web daemon.
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: web.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: web.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 05:36:03 ip-172-31-63-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start web.service - This is web daemon.
```

I packed binary with:

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bin/application`

When I run same binary locally all works fine

When deploying Docker, it failed to recognize one of my packages

`Failed to resolve github.com/<my username>/<project name>/api`

I understand that the current directory is /var/app/current, so would it help if I use relative paths when importing module?

Like instead of

```
. "github.com/<username>/<project name>/api"
```

to try with

```
"<project name>/api"
```

What would be the recommended way here?

And even when I removed all included packages from main and left only this

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"


)

const (
    PORT = 8080
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/hello", helloWorld()).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", router))
}

func helloWorld() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        writer.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
    }
}
```

it failed again with

```
 > [4/4] RUN go build GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o application:
4.054 malformed import path "GOOS=linux": invalid char '='
4.064 malformed import path "GOARCH=amd64": invalid char '='
4.064 package go: no Go files in /usr/local/go/src/go
4.064 package build is not in std (/usr/local/go/src/build)
4.064 malformed import path "-o": leading dash
4.064 package application is not in std (/usr/local/go/src/application)
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.21.3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN go build GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o application

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./application"]
```

It also failed when deploying this version from binary

As you could see, I'm using go modules here in my project

I would prefer to make it working with Go as a platform. Its quite easy to pack binary and just deploy.

To sum it up:

1. How could I get more detailed error when deploying as Go platform?
2. What could be an issue here?
3. What is the recommended way for including packages from the same project, to make it work both locally and when deploying to cloud?

Bear in mind I'm pretty new to Golang
Thanks in advance